# Call a sproc passing parameters from different sproc in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing some custom reports for some 3rd party software. The software provides stored procedures from which to get my data.

One of the new requirements for my report is to get the data for an order, then if there is an associated order, then run the same sproc using the associated order's data.

**Basically:**

Order #1 is associated with Order #2, I need to:

1. Run sproc GetOrderInfo (pass parameter OrderId = 1)
2. Look at field AssociatedOrderId (in this case it equals a string value of "2", but could be null or even a blank string [I know I know, but I don't own the database design])
3. Run sproc GetOrderInfo (pass parameter OrderId = 2 [OrderId is an int])
4. Display report

Is this possible in Crystal reports? I cannot see a way to set the parameter of the sproc based on other sproc's returned values.

Database is SqlServer, but I doubt that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subreport, base it on the same stored procedure and link the parameters values of the subreport to a field in the main report

Comment: [facepalm], thanks, I totally forgot about subreports for some reason. It's one of those days I guess.